# Image not (correctly?) resized on BatchUpdateRequest; doesn't fit initial space

Tags: c#, image, google-docs-api

I am updating a Google Document using BatchRequest and I especially want to update some images.
My issue is: if I don't resize (crop white spaces arround) my images, it is correctly displayed in my doc, but when I resize it, Google Docs seems to not be able to adapt it automatically to the initial size/area.

Here is my code:

Image resizing:

```
public static Bitmap Crop(Bitmap bmp)
{
    int w = bmp.Width;
    int h = bmp.Height;

    Func<int, bool> allWhiteRow = row =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < w; ++i)
            if (bmp.GetPixel(i, row).R != 255)
                return false;
        return true;
    };

    Func<int, bool> allWhiteColumn = col =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
            if (bmp.GetPixel(col, i).R != 255)
                return false;
        return true;
    };

    int topmost = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < h; ++row)
    {
        if (allWhiteRow(row))
            topmost = row;
        else break;
    }

    int bottommost = 0;
    for (int row = h - 1; row >= 0; --row)
    {
        if (allWhiteRow(row))
            bottommost = row;
        else break;
    }

    int leftmost = 0, rightmost = 0;
    for (int col = 0; col < w; ++col)
    {
        if (allWhiteColumn(col))
            leftmost = col;
        else
            break;
    }

    for (int col = w - 1; col >= 0; --col)
    {
        if (allWhiteColumn(col))
            rightmost = col;
        else
            break;
    }

    if (rightmost == 0) rightmost = w; // As reached left
    if (bottommost == 0) bottommost = h; // As reached top.

    int croppedWidth = rightmost - leftmost;
    int croppedHeight = bottommost - topmost;

    if (croppedWidth == 0) // No border on left or right
    {
        leftmost = 0;
        croppedWidth = w;
    }

    if (croppedHeight == 0) // No border on top or bottom
    {
        topmost = 0;
        croppedHeight = h;
    }

    try
    {
        var target = new Bitmap(croppedWidth, croppedHeight);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            g.DrawImage(bmp,
            new RectangleF(0, 0, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
            new RectangleF(leftmost, topmost, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
            GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        
        return target;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(
        string.Format("Values are topmost={0} btm={1} left={2} right={3} croppedWidth={4} croppedHeight={5}", topmost, bottommost, leftmost, rightmost, croppedWidth, croppedHeight),
        ex);
    }
}
```

(I also tried to resize it by using Clone method, but can't see any difference)

crop call: (original is a PNG)

```
Bitmap originalBmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(str);

Bitmap cropedBmp = ImageUtilities.Crop(originalBmp);
```

and my code to update images in doc:

```
BatchUpdateDocumentRequest batchUpdateRequest = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest {
    Requests = new List<Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data.Request>()
};
var request = new Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data.Request {
    ReplaceImage = new ReplaceImageRequest() {
        ImageObjectId = imageObjectId,
        Uri = imgUrl,
        ImageReplaceMethod = "CENTER_CROP"
    }
};

batchUpdateRequest.Requests.Add(request);
DocumentsResource.BatchUpdateRequest updateRequest = 
    _docSercive.Documents.BatchUpdate(batchUpdateRequest, doc.DocumentId);

BatchUpdateDocumentResponse updateResponse = updateRequest.Execute();
```

All this results in an image which is correctly resized, but not correctly inserted in the doc.
For instance:

Here is the generated image:
[![Resized generated mage][1]][1]

and here is how it is displayed in the doc:
[![how it is displayed in the doc after replacement][2]][2]

Any idea?

Thanks!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZF7M.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ9lX.png

Comment: I suspect that the C# side of this is irrelevant - if you've got the image somewhere you can refer to it, you could presumably test all of this using the Google API Explorer at https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate. If you create the PNG using something like Paint .NET instead, do you get the same results?

Comment: nope, the issue is caused by the resizing, I guess. If I use the initial image (streamed form somewhere else), no issue but big white spaces arround the image, that's why I need croping it :p. I assume, I probably miss some properties or metadata?

Comment: So have you tried resizing in any other way, e.g. with Paint .NET, ImageMagick, etc? And have you tried using the API via the API explorer? Basically you've got two bits of C# here, and I suspect only one of them is relevant, but at the moment we can't tell *exactly* which.

Comment: And if you replace it *manually* in the document (i.e. using the Google Docs UI) with the image cropped by the C# code, does that still cause a problem?

Comment: if I resize it manually (whatever the tool, including my code) and replace the image manually, there's no problem. I didn't tried the API explorer, I will do it

Comment: Okay, so it the same image produces different results based on whether you replace with with the API or with code, that suggests the image itself is less relevant - so you can concentrate on the API part.

Comment: okay, I just tried API explorer and the result is the same: inserted image is croped when using API insert... that confirms that the issue is probably somewhere on the API part

Comment: Right. At that point, I suspect it's best to update your question with all this information - and you can probably safely remove the image cropping code, given that the image is fine when doing it manually. I don't have any more advice to give, in that I know about Google APIs in general but not the details of the Docs API implementation. Good luck though!

Comment: cannot reproduce this behaviour using https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZF7M.png as the URL - maybe there is something about the structure of your document (in this case, please share a sample document that would reproduce this issue). In any case, try modifying `ImageReplaceMethod = "CENTER_CROP"` to `ImageReplaceMethod = "IMAGE_REPLACE_METHOD_UNSPECIFIED"`